# getting NULL with cURL but Array with file_get_contents()

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, file-get-contents

I'm having problem with CURL from a link. I'm able to get an output with `file_get_contents();` But having problems with CURL

use `json_decode` I get a NULL with `cURL`, but with `file_get_contents()` I get an Array

Using `cURL`

```
$url="https://example.com/" 
$ch= curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
$json= json_decode(curl_exec($ch),true); 
echo $json; //outputs NULL
```

Using `file_get_contents();`

```
$json_pi = file_get_contents($url); 
echo json_decode($json_pi,true);
```

Can anyone help me understand cURL? And why I might be getting these two conflicting results?

Thank you!

Comment: Nobody can tell without a concrete example and the json input data. Possibly charsets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing any error checking after your calls, so if something goes wrong, you will never hear about it.

- Check the result of the CURL call using [`curl_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)
- Check the result of the json_encode() call using [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) (PHP >= 5.3)

one of these will probably reveal what the problem is. For example, it could be that the curl call fetches the data in a non-UTF-8 character set, which will cause `json_decode()` to break - it expects UTF-8 data at all times.

Comment: I'm getting this using curl_error() `Warning: curl_error() expects exactly 1 parameter, 0 given in C:\wamp\www\`

Comment: @andrew see the manual link for how it's used. `echo curl_error($ch);`

Comment: Nice, I figured it out. Thanks!